# How to create a wordpress on Bluemix

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud

I want to create a Wordpress site on Bluemix, though the service is not active anymore. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Would Wordpress within a docker container be an option?

Comment: It seems that this answer should be the right way! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1) [Wordpress in a Docker Container](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/). This is the easiest solution and allows for an infinite amount of customization and portability. [See this guide](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html) for creating a container on Bluemix.

2) [Follow this guide for creating a Wordpress environment on Bluemix](https://hub.jazz.net/project/jstart/WordPress%20on%20Bluemix/overview?cm_mc_uid=91315046672114537548574&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1454710153). It is a pretty techincal setup and in my opinion, the more difficult and error prone way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I already tried the second option which didn't work (and I guess I was too impatient to debug). I'll try the container.